# How to Add Image In List View in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have windows application where data comes via json I have parsed the data and able to show in listview.

Now i want to add image to with in. I have tried lot oh things but this is not working.
As per my need.

Please guide how i will show this data in list box.

I am using this code.

```
listView1.Columns.Add("brand", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("rating", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("max_price", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

foreach (var item in lstItemDetails)
{
    ListViewItem objListViewItem = new ListViewItem(item.image_medium);
    objListViewItem.SubItems.Add(item.brand);

    objListViewItem.SubItems.Add(item.rating);
    objListViewItem.SubItems.Add(item.max_price);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.rating))
    {
        int rating = int.Parse(item.rating);
        objListViewItem.ImageIndex = rating;
    }
    else
    {
        objListViewItem.ImageIndex = 0;
    }

     listView1.Items.Add(objListViewItem);
}
```

This is showing only last assigned image in all place. start rating image as per item.rating count.

Please suggest me the better way to solve this.

Comment: If you have an item reating the image index becomes 0. So all the items in the list that have a rating end up with the same image.

Comment: The code that initializes imageList1 is missing.  So that's probably the cause of the problem.  Make sure to *add* images to the ImageList, not replace them.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing anything with a ListView, you do yourself a huge favour and use an [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) instead. ObjectListView is a wrapper around a standard .NET ListView which provides methods for just about everything you could want to do, plus fixes for almost all the problems/bugs that ListView has.

For example, it can build your whole ListView -- complete with sorting, grouping, and editing -- by just creating the columns and then calling `SetObjects()`

[image]